# Encrypting/Decrypting a single file in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I need to be able to encrypt/decrypt a single text file stored on my external HD in 12.04 LTS, preferably a GUI application, if any, or the command line otherwise. Thank you.

Answer (score 48):

A simple way to encrypt a single file is with `openssl`:

```
openssl des3 < youfile.txt > yourfile.txt.des3
```

This will prompt you for a passphrase, which you will need to enter later when decrypting the file.

```
openssl des3 -d < yourfile.txt.des3 > yourfile.txt.decrypted
```

To make this "graphical" you could put it in a `Nautilus` script and make it accessible from the context menu. (See the docs of `Nautilus` for that.)

**UPDATE**

`des3` is just an example. Run `openssl enc -ciphers` or `openssl list -cipher-algorithms` to see the full list of ciphers.

Comment: Why `des3`? You can do much better encryption faster with `openssl aes-128-cbc`

Comment: @BrendanLong: I guess the reason is that `aes-128-cbc` in not mentioned in `man openssl` - I wonder why. It works, though.

Comment: Note, I just tried to encrypt a file on Ubuntu with des and decrypt it on Windows, and got an error `7C230000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_block.c:124`

Answer (score 30):

Lets assume that a person wants to encrypt a file called '**message.txt**':

## 1. Encrypting a file using GPG, for personal use

### I. Using a passphrase to encrypt the file (and not the private key)

**I.i**. The command:
`gpg -c message.txt`
does it; it asks for a password (and a password confirmation) and generates an encrypted 'message.txt.gpg', which is binary.

**I.ii**. If you want to generate an ASCII encrypted file, which is base64(i think) of that file, you can use
`gpg -c --armor message.txt` 
This will generate an 'message.txt.asc', which is the same as the generated by the command before, but base64 coded, i.e., the encrypted file in text mode (**.asc**, not binary as **.gpg** would be).

### II. Using a private key to  encrypt a file

**II.i**. If you want to encrypt a file using your key, instead of only a passphare, use the command `gpg -e -r 'yourname' message.txt`.
The argument 'yourname' should contain a part of the name that you used to create the private key. If you dont give the -r parameter, gpg will ask for it. You can type our name then (the same that you would type on command line).

**II.ii**. Point II.i would give you a binary file. If you want to get an ASCII file, use --armor. `gpg -e -r 'yourname' --armor message.txt`.

## 2. Decrypting the file encrypted with GPG

To decrypt, the file, use the command `gpg -d --output OUTPUTFILE message.txt.gpg`. This will ask for the passphrase and then decrypt the file **message.txt.gpg** to **OUTPUTFILE**, if the passphrase is correct. This passhrase is that which you used directly (point I., the `-c` parameter), or through your private key (point II., the `-e` parameter) This works for both binary (.gpg) or ascii (.asc) files. If you supress the `--output FILE`, it is outputted to console (stdout), then you can do this also, that is, redirect it to a file: `gpg -d message.txt.gpg > OUTPUTFILE.txt` Both do the same. 8 )

Answer (score 3):

Try http://www.aescrypt.com/ it works great.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811528/can-i-use-my-ssh-public-key-to-decrypt-a-file
Is a question on a related subject. You can use the same principles for encryption if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

For (GnuPG) 1.4.16

```
gpg -a --output outfile.txt --encrypt infile.txt
```

You will next be prompted:

```
Enter the user ID.  End with an empty line:
```

where the "user ID" can be found by running

```
gpg --list-keys
```