# How to encrypt folder once, for sending?

Tags: encryption

Most encryption programs seem to be made for encrypting a folder permanently.

I, however, simply want to encrypt a folder *once* and send it as an email attachment to someone. I feel like TrueCrypt, encfs, and others are used for constant encryption.

What program can do this?

Comment: try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unix philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) favors composability over monolythic design. In this sense, your problem can be split into two separate problems:

**- How do I bundle a folder into a single file suitable for sending?**

You can do that with `tar` command:

```
tar zcf ./myfiles.tar.gz ./myfolder/
```

**- How do I encrypt a single file?**

There's already an [answer for that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160253/encrypting-decrypting-a-single-file-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts). For example:

```
openssl des3 < ./myfiles.tar.gz > ./myfiles.tar.gz.des3
```

To decrypt the file you can then use

```
openssl des3 -d < ./myfiles.tar.gz.des3 > ./myfiles-decrypted.tar.gz
```

And, finally, to "untar" the file into a directory:

```
tar zxf ./myfiles-decrypted.tar.gz
```

Comment: You're right, I should've thought of it that way. Thanks.