# encrypt shared folder in attached filesystem on external device

Tags: mount, encryption

I have an external file server which a few people use as a backup server. I have a folder in the file server mounted on my machine as a shared folder. Every week, I copy over some sensitive files from my local hard drive into the shared folder. How can I encrypt those files such that no one else that has access to that file server can see their contents?

Moreover, if my local hard drive crashes, I'd like to be able to access these encrypted files from the external file server using the same encryption/decryption credentials (duh)

Sorry if I was repetitive, thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't a full answer to your question because it isn't for folders, but gpg can encrypt/decrypt single files with a password. See https://askubuntu.com/a/424193/115738 (if you do the private key one, you'll need the private key to decrypt, which might not be best for backups.)

Comment: What about having a Veracrypt container on the file server?