# Password protect certain application

Tags: password, security

I want to password protect certain application in my desktop application. For example, everytime open firefox I want to set a password for it so that opening firefox should ask for password. I want to do the same for libre office as well. So when I open libre office, it should ask for password. And the password should be different for each different application. Is there any way to do this? I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's possible: [encrypt the executable for each program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160253/encrypting-decrypting-a-single-file-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts) with a different password and change the [desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857896/why-is-this-file-name-truncated-in-nautilus) of the application to include the decrypt command.